# Directory into an Array then sort its files by creation date

Tags: vb.net

I need to sort a directories files by it's creation date. I have looked at solutions here and on the web ; which point mostly to linq usage which i can't use as my application is a legacy one with .net framework 2.0. I am also using .net vb. Other solutions require a class which I don't want to use either. I need a simple sort solution which will display all my files in an array sorted from lowest date to highest date of file creation.

Below is code which I am currently using ; which by default sorts by file name.

```
            Dim trydef1 As String = D_Drive & "\Cloud Documents\"

            Dim txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(trydef1)

            For Each filenm As String In txtFiles
            'process the file here
            Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use lambda expressions, you must use a class. There is nothing evil about classes. Use `Array.Sort` in conjunction with a custom comparer. The only other way without using a class, is to implement a sorting algorithm like QuickSort yourself. It is easier to write a class.

A comparer returns a negative value if the first value is less than the second value, returns 0 if both are equal and returns a positive value if the first is greater then the second.

```
public static void Sort (Array array, System.Collections.IComparer comparer);
```

You must write a custom comparer yourself. You can write a function in a Class much like you would in a Module. The main difference in usage is that a class is a template for the creation of objects. Therefore you must create an object with `New FileByDateComparer()`. The advantage is that you can pass this object as a parameter to the `Array.Sort` method. Something you cannot do with Modules.

```
Public Class FileByDateComparer
    Implements IComparer

    Public Function Compare(a As Object, b As Object) As Integer _
        Implements IComparer.Compare

        Dim fileA = DirectCast(a, FileInfo)
        Dim fileB = DirectCast(b, FileInfo)
        Dim comp = fileA.CreationTime.CompareTo(fileB.CreationTime)

        If comp <> 0 Then 'Dates are different
            Return comp
        End If

        'Dates are equal, sort by name
        Return fileA.Name.CompareTo(fileB.Name)
    End Function
End Class
```

The comparer assumes that it is passed `FileInfo` objects and not file names as string.

```
Dim files As FileInfo() = New DirectoryInfo(trydef1).GetFiles()
Array.Sort(files, New FileByDateComparer())

For Each fileInfo As FileInfo In files
    Console.WriteLine($"{fileInfo.Name} {fileInfo.CreationTime}")
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver ! works well - however I did not understand  this line :- public static void Sort (Array array, System.Collections.IComparer comparer);

Comment: This shows how the `Sort` method has been declared by Microsoft. It shows that it has a second parameter `IComparer comparer`. You don't have to write it. It's only for info.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use LINQ, you're basically iterating through the collection and doing something that you had to do manually pre-3.5. Here is how I'd do it in legacy applications:

```
' Get all of the files in the directory
Dim filenames() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("test-directory")
Dim timestamps(filenames.Length - 1) As DateTime

' Get the creation time of each file
For index As Integer = 0 To filenames.Length - 1
    timestamps(index) = IO.File.GetCreationTime(filenames(index))
Next

' Sort the data (in this case it is a bubble sort)
Dim swapped As Boolean
Do
    swapped = False
    For index As Integer = 1 To timestamps.Length - 1
        If (timestamps(index - 1) > timestamps(index)) Then
            Dim swappingFilename As String = filenames(index - 1)
            Dim swappingTiemstamp As DateTime = timestamps(index - 1)
            filenames(index - 1) = filenames(index)
            timestamps(index - 1) = timestamps(index)
            filenames(index) = swappingFilename
            timestamps(index) = swappingTiemstamp

            swapped = True
        End If
    Next
Loop Until Not swapped
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VG8YXa)